# Given Electric Field Find Charge Distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

The electric field is $\vec{E}=2xy \hat{x}+x^2\hat{y}$. Find the charge distribution that generated this field.

My solution is based on differential form of Gauss's Law:

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}= \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$$

I just simply plunged the electric field into the equation and I get:

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot (2xy \hat{x}+x^2\hat{y})= \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$$
This gives:

$$2y\varepsilon_0=\rho$$

I know this is wrong, since the density should be a constant right? I just dont know what my mistake is.

Comment: the density is not, in general,  a constant! it is a function of position (x,y)

Comment: @Wolphramjonny So at $y=0$ we would say that there is no charge density?

Comment: I would say it is zero, but the way you say it I would not say is less correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have your electric field $\vec{E}$ in two dimensions and you are using the Gauss’s Law to determine the charge distribution.

I was checking and you used it right, the calculations are right, and I’m pretty sure that is the answer.

Although, the charge distribution don’t have to be a constant, in this case, we expect to have a well known function of $(x,y)$ that will give us information of how the charges are distributed in the plane.

IF the answer was a constante it would mean that for all $(x,y)$ you have the same number of charges, and that means that the charge would be equally distributed in the plane. But that’s not always the case one meet.

Hope to help you!